# Cannot find symbol variable in Layout. How to solve this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android programming I'm getting an error in Android Studio on the last statement 'cannot find symbol variable ll'. How can I solve this error?

```
LinearLayout root ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
    root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have a linear layout with id 'll'. This error will occur if you have not assigned the correct id.

Comment: I've done that and it's working fine thank you. Another problem when I ran the app it gives me a blank page other than what I designed and wrote any ideas why is that?

Comment: Probably you forgot to use **setContentView** there or used wrong layout